# Geometric series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, summation

Suppose $$X = 1.05^{35}v+1.05^{34}v^{2} + \cdots + 1.05v^{35}$$ where $v = 1/1.05$. Then we have $$X = 1.05^{35}v(1+ 0.952v+ \cdots + 0.952^{34}v^{34})$$

So the sum of this would be $$ X = 1.05^{35}v \left[\frac{1-\left(\frac{1+952v}{1.05} \right)^{35}}{1-\frac{1+.952v}{1.05}} \right]$$

Is that right?

Comment: Except that $1/1.05\ne .952$. (this will be important when taking a big power)

Comment: So, to clarify, the sum in question is $X=\sum_{i=1}^{35} 1.05^{36-i}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{i}$ ?

Comment: Additionally, what is the context of this problem?  It looks closest to finding the PV of a growing annunity, but its not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the sum of a finite [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) is $\sum_{k=0}^n ar^k = \frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}$. You correctly factored out $a=1.05^{35}v$, so identifying $r=v/1.05$, we have,
$$\begin{align}
X
&= 1.05^{35}v+1.05^{34}v^{2} + \cdots + 1.05v^{35} \\
&= 1.05^{35}v\left(1+\frac{v}{1.05}+\frac{v^2}{1.05^2}+\cdots+\frac{v^{34}}{1.05^{34}}\right) \\
&= 1.05^{35}v \left(\sum_{k=0}^{34} \left(\frac{v}{1.05}\right)^k\right) \\
&= \frac{1.05^{35}v\left(1-\left(\frac{v}{1.05}\right)^{35}\right)}{1-\frac{v}{1.05}}.
\end{align}$$

Your identification of $r$ is not quite correct.

Comment: I just rounded $r$.

Comment: If you didn't round, your choice would be $r=\frac{1+(1/1.05)}{1.05}v$. This is not the same as $r=\frac{v}{1.05}$.

Comment: Your $r$ and my $r$ are in different contexts. I am using the following formula: $S = (\text{first term}) \frac{[1-(\text{ratio})^{\text{no. of terms}}]}{1-\text{ratio}}$ where $\text{ratio} = \frac{1+r}{1+i}$. So my $r$ is $1/1.05^{2}$.

Comment: I am using $r$ as the ratio of terms in the series, which is simply $v/1.05$. The formula you posted for the ratio seems to be related to interest rates, which wasn't explicitly mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @james $r=\frac{v}{1.05}$ in dls's answer is $\frac{1}{1.05^2}$ as well.

Comment: @DrewChristianson How do you get that? The original post gives no particular value for $v$, but you're assuming $v=1/1.05$.

Comment: @Drew Christianson: I know that's what I pointed out. It's the same.

Comment: @dls: I did say $v = 1/1.05$.

Comment: Wow, completely missed that. Then you can simplify the original expression to $X=1.05^{34}+1.05^{32}+\cdots+1.05^{-32}+1.05^{-34}$ and apply the formula for the geometric series. But my answer still holds for any $v$.

Answer (score 0):

So I worked through the entire problem, and then realized I'd done exactly what dls already had posted.  However, I arrived at the answer in a slightly different manner (eliminating the v) that felt slightly more intuitive to me.  So:

If I'm interpreting your sequence correctly, you want the sum:
 $$x=\sum_{i=1}^{35}1.05^{36-i}*\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^i = 1.05^{35}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{1}+1.05^{34}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{2} + \cdots + 1.05^{1}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{35}$$

Then we factor $1.05^{35}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{}$, giving:

$$1.05^{35}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{}\left[1 + \left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{4}+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{68}\right]$$

$$ = 1.05^{35}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{}\left[\left(\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^2\right)^{0}+\left(\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^2\right)^{1}+\left(\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^2\right)^{2}+\cdots+\left(\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^2\right)^{34}\right] $$

$$=1.05^{35}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{} \sum_{i=0}^{34}\left(\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^2\right)^{i}$$

Which is just a geometric series with $r=\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^2$.  Thus, X is given by the formula $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k= a \, \frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$.  Filling in the values from above:

$$X=1.05^{35}\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{}\frac{1-\left[\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^2\right]^{35}}{1-\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^2} = 54.6484...$$

Finally, I verified the final value numerically in maple and everything checks out.

On an aside regarding david's comment on rounding:  I think this derivation lets you see why rounding $\frac{1}{1.05}$ to .952 causes problems.  The final term is a 68th power, so that small error can grow.  Numerically, $.952^{68} = .0352624\ldots$ while $\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{68} = .036234\ldots$ A thousandth might not seem like much, but over 35 terms, you could be off by a third of a one percent - significant for large financial calculations.  Moreover, if this was monthly or daily interest (and thus you were taking powers to the hundreds or thousands) those errors could really add up.

Comment: Hence the frequent admonition: *round only at the end!* Keep as many figures as you can in intermediate calculations; it's not always easy to tell which parts of your long calculation will be a source of grief.